# Bad timer in Windows service

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

i have timer in my windows service, but the windows service does not do what it should do..
I want ask you, if i have good code with timer?

Part of my code (updated):

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(getFileList);
    timer.Interval = 10000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.AutoReset = false;
}

private void getFileList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Work with xml...                
    DeleteOldBackupFiles();
}

private void DeleteOldBackupFiles()
{
    string[] Oldfiles = Directory.GetFiles(backup);
    foreach (string Ofile in Oldfiles)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Ofile);
        if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2))
        {
            fi.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

After your ideas i edit my code, but result is the same..

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(getFileList);
    timer.Interval = 10000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
}
```

Comment: What does it do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Of course you can't start the timer before you create it...

Comment: after 10 second jump to getFileList...stop timer...do getFileList...

Comment: Interval is milliseconds, not seconds. You should set it to 10000. Also, you might as well set AutoReset to false, and remove the timer.Stop() from the top of getFileList. Also, Start() and Enabled = true do the same thing. You only need one of those.

Comment: After your edit, what is it still doing wrong?

Comment: @hatchet: It not doing ...The code take xml file, and data from xml and give it to database, after that delete file from ftp...but now doesnt do nothing from this

Comment: @Kate - you need to verify whether the timer is firing or not. You can do this by using a debugger and setting a breakpoint, or by writing a message to the EventLog at the top of your getFileList method. From the symptoms you've described, there could be a hundred causes, some of which have nothing to do with the Timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have most likely an error somewhere in your timer making it throw an exception. You will not detect that since `System.Timers.Timer` silently ignores all unhandled exceptions.

You'll therefore have to wrap all code with a try/catch block:

```
private void getFileList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         DeleteOldBackupFiles();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         //log exception or just put a breakpoint here.
     }
}
```

Hence your timer is working, but you are doing something wrong in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would change it to this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(getFileList);
            timer.Interval = 10000;
            timer.AutoReset = false;
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
 private void getFileList(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(****);
```

Setting [AutoReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx) to false causes the Timer to fire just once. In other words, it's like an automatic Stop after the first firing of the Timer. So doing that means you don't need to Stop() the Timer in your getFileList method. This is an important distinction when the Timer interval is small. If you set AutoReset to true and call Stop() at the top of your handler, there's a small chance that your method will get called more than once. Setting AutoReset to false is a more definitive way to get the behaviour you desire.

Calling Start() and setting Enabled to true are redundant, so I removed the Start().

Interval is milliseconds, so I changed that to 10000.

Comment: But i need stop the timer when is the program in the getFileList...It is possible?

Comment: Still nothing...when i used the code in winform aplication it run, but in service dont run :/ In winform app i havent timer...there is error maybe..:/

Comment: @Kate There isn't "maybe" an error, either there is or there isn't. If there is you need to post here with details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are having an Exception thrown somewhere in `getFileList`, possibly because the service is running with a Current Directory of `c:\windows\system32\`.

Add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` then add `Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;` in your `void Main(...)` before your service is created.

as @jgauffin pointed out, you should wrap your `getFileList` body in a 'try catch' and log the error to some absolute path like `c:\errors.txt`. otherwise you are just guessing whats wrong.