# Service not run again

Tags: c#, windows-services

i have windows service. The program jump to getFileList, after that jump to DeleteOldBackupFiles and after that nothing...the program not run again and I dont know why..Have you any idea?
Example of my code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(getFileList);
    timer.Interval = 10000;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
}

private void getFileList(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    if (!Directory.Exists(backup))
    {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(backup);
    } 

    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(*****);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(***, ***);
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            files.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }

        files.Remove(".");
        files.Remove("..");
        reader.Close();

        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        //getFileList();                
    }

    if (files.Count != 0)
    {
        //timer.Stop();
        foreach (string file in files)
        {    
            //Work with XML file and give data to sql
        }
    }

    DeleteOldBackupFiles();
}

private void DeleteOldBackupFiles()
{
    string[] Oldfiles = Directory.GetFiles(backup);
    foreach (string Ofile in Oldfiles)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Ofile);
        if (fi.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2))
        {
            fi.Delete();
        }
    }               
}
```

I want after DeleteOldBackupFiles, run OnStart again...

Comment: `AutoReset = false;`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: with true I have the same problem...

Comment: You call `getFileList` on a timer that does not get reset (`timer.AutoReset = false`), and so it gets called once.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: when i have reset=true i have the same problem..:/

Comment: @Kate - do you really have the *same* problem or do you get some kind of exception that either a) You've not told us about, or b) Some piece of the code you've not shown us silently catches and doesn't tell anyone about?

Comment: Also @Kate, isn't this same problem you asked in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771565/bad-timer-in-windows-service

Comment: If all your service does is wait on a timer, and then do something interesting, consider using the Windows Task Scheduler -- it doesn't require another process running all of the time.

Comment: @Moo-Juice: No, this problem i repaired....

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe : I have edited my first post and give them more my code..

Comment: As has been mentioned, you're probably getting an exception in getFileList, but it's not enough to just catch the exception and ignore it, you need to act on it. Windows is trying to tell you what's wrong! You need to log the exception somehow so you can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
 timer.AutoReset = false;
```

Delete it or set it to `true` (default) because that's mean your event-handler will be called *only* once.

**Update:**
If that does not help you, than I would suggust you to debug it using: [Debugger.Launch();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx)

Comment: I try it, but the same problem...:/

Comment: An alternative she can use is `Debugger.Break` if the service is already running.

Comment: Or you could paste your code into a normal Windows application (as opposed to a service), and debug it that way.

Comment: @Surfbutler Or a console application..More simple ;-)